# How to print an output message in SQL oracle if a condition within a function is not met

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, output

How can I add an output message to a function if a reimbursement request is not approved?

This is the code of my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION reimbursement_check(CREATIONDATE DATE) 
RETURN  DATE
IS
M_DATE DATE ;
BEGIN 
SELECT UpdateDate
      INTO M_DATE
      FROM REIMBURSEMENTREQUEST
      WHERE ReimbursementStatus = 'APPR'
AND UpdateDate = CREATIONDATE;
M_DATE := CREATIONDATE + 7;
RETURN M_DATE;
END;
```

Comment: Reimbursement status will not equal 'NOTA, because you specify reimbursementStatus = 'APPR' in the WHERE clause. If you want to report that no approved record was returned, you can use WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND dbms_output etc

Comment: You right, that definitely can work. I just realized that I was not more specific, there is also another status. Which is the submitted status. I think WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND dbms_output etc works better when there is only 2 status. Does the SUBMITTEED status changes things? Sorry if I'm asking simple questions. I'm just new to SQL.

Comment: Generally speaking, your idea is a bad idea. If anyone uses a tool that isn't capable of displaying result of dbms_output.put_line (such as Oracle Apex, Oracle Forms, ...), nobody will see any "message". I guess end users won't be calling that function from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. Therefore, you'd rather find another option. As function returns DATE datatype, you - obviously - can't return that message (as it is a string). Besides, SELECT statement isn't even checking "ReimbursementStatus" - it is used in WHERE clause. A lot of questions here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah got it. In that case, I can use apex_application.g_print_success_message := instead.

Comment: Is the question about "printing" something in Apex (which I don't know at all) or returning something from a PL/SQL function (which I am very familiar with)?

Comment: Also just from a code review perspective, why `m_`? Normally I see `l_` (local) or `v_` (variable). Also it's worth formatting code (and I don't mean pressing the 'format' button in your IDE).

Comment: Its about adjusting the function to print a message in Apex if the ReimbursementStatus = 'NOTA'. And thanks for the suggestion

Comment: _"ts about adjusting the function to print a message"_   That's a bad use of a function.  A function should return a single value of a defined type.  Think about TO_DATE()  or SYSDATE for examples of how a _function_ should be used and behave.  Rather than try to magicaly change the type/and value returned, think about RAISEing an application error, and allowing the procedure that called the function to handle the raised error.

Comment: I see, you make very good points @EdStevens. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reimbursement_check(p_creation_date DATE) 
RETURN  DATE
IS
  l_date   DATE;
  l_status REIMBURSEMENTREQUEST.ReimbursementStatus%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN

    SELECT UpdateDate, ReimbursementStatus 
      INTO l_date, l_status
      FROM REIMBURSEMENTREQUEST
     WHERE UpdateDate = p_creation_date;

  EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
    NULL; --or however it should be handled
  END;

  IF l_status = 'NOTA' THEN
    apex_error.add_error(
      p_message => 'Not approved for receiving a reimbursement check', 
      p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification);
  END IF;

  RETURN p_creation_date + 7;
END;
/
```

Comment: No I did not. Thank you Gnqz, that is way beyond what I had in mind.